# how do I set up rounding_method with the Ruby Money gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, currency

We're using the Ruby Money gem.  It works great.

We now have a new requirement to round the converted currency amount to whole dollar (without
the pennies).

I have found Ruby's round method for Fixnum

190.round(-1)   returns  200
149.round(-1)   returns  100

which is what I want.

I see that Money::Bank::VariableExchange class supports a rounding_method.

I can get a handle to the bank object by calling

Money.default_bank

but how do I register or assign the rounding method to the Money.default_bank object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use the Bank VariableExchange:

```
Money.default_bank = Money::Bank::VariableExchange.new { |n| n.round(-2) }
```

Will set your default bank to use the VariableExchange, and round exchanges to the nearest dollar.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation:

http://rubydoc.info/github/RubyMoney/money/Money/Bank/Base#rounding_method-instance_method

Looks like you need to create a bank as:

```
Money::Bank::Base.new {|n| n.round(-1) }
```

Comment: Hi. We're using Money::Bank::VariableExchange, which has the code:

Comment: it uses methods: marshal_dump and marshal_load

Comment: this is all about bank creation, you need to define the rounding mechanism when you setup your first bank, i.e. the object that is referred to when you use Money.default_bank